Return DistinguishedName using ComputerPrincipal from ActiveDirectory
I want to get the DistinguishedName using ComputerPrincipal from the Active Directory only for the user that is signed in.
With the code below the searchResultOrgUnit returns me all PC's that are registered in the AD but when I want to filter by the name of the pc and check if it contains the users firstname, it returns me null (even though I can clearly see that there is a row with the same/similar name that contains the user.firstname.
I have tried smth like this:
using (var OrgUnitsearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(adContext)))
{
    OrgUnitsearcher.QueryFilter = new ComputerPrincipal(adContext)
    {
        Enabled = true
    };

    var searchResultOrgUnit = OrgUnitsearcher.FindAll();

    if (searchResultOrgUnit is null)
        return userResponse; 

    var computerPrincipal = searchResultOrgUnit.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name.Contains(userResponse.FirstName));
    if (computerPrincipal != null)
    {
        userResponse.organizationalUnit = computerPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
    }

    return userResponse;

}


You are never setting userResponse.

@jdweng I am setting userResponse.organizationalUnit at the bottom of the code

Have you checked the case of the PC name against the case of userResponse.FirstName?

What do you see when you step through the code? Do you see the list of computers with the value in it? Also, should your Contains test be case-insensitive?

@stuartd I see all my computers that are registered in the AD.
Btw, yea unfortunately that was the problem. It couldnt filter the data because I was looking for "John" in "JOHNPC". Gonna delete the question a little bit later :(
